# ArcPy RemoveLayer doesn't work

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers

I have a task where I have several polygons and I have several data frames in which each has a different temporal image. I have linked the data frames to one main data frame in which I add a polygon and all the data frames zoom to that extent of the main frame and I have to export the map. I have thousands of polygons I have managed to automate the process. Problem is I need to delete the shapefile once the map is exported and add the next shapefile. The remove layer doesn't work and the maps show overlaying boundaries.
Code:

```py
folder = "D:\TNIAMP\shapes"
arcpy.env.workspace = folder
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
for fc in fcList:
    shape = arcpy.mapping.Layer(fc)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, shape)
    ext = shape.getExtent()
    df.extent = ext
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd,"D:\TNIAMP\shapes\maps\{0}.jpg".format(Tank_name))
    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, shape)
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
    mxd.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issues is that your layer object `shape` is constructed from a Feature Class which you then *add* to the map. It is not a layer you have *found* in a map. Look at the [sample code](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/analyze/arcpy-mapping/removelayer.htm#C_GUID-5620A6E7-5C68-4B1C-B03E-0DEC9D6BF518) in the help file, see how they remove layers that were *found* in the map.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
```

and it worked...